# Debugging and CDK deployment conflict

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I have a small Nodejs Lambda function that I want to be able to debug locally and then deploy using a CDK script.

To get the debug working I need to add "type": "module" to my package.json. However, if I keep this setting in when I run CDK Synth, I get the error

> TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts"
> for E:\Code\Github\Maintel\Major Incident
> Alert\AWS\infrastructure\Launcher.ts

If I remove it, the CDK Synth works, but I can't debug the Lambda function locally.

What's going on here then? Yes, I could workaround by keeping the setting in for dev and removing for deployment, but that's not a great solutino

Comment: `To get the debug working I need to add "type": "module" to my package.json. However, if I keep this setting in when I run CDK Synth, I get the error` - type: module means that your code should use `import` syntax instead of `require()`. That's it. You should be able debug project without adding `"type": "module"` to the package.json.

Comment: Could you please add to your question the following? 1. What tools are you using to debug your lambda function? 2. Was the lambda function written in pure js, or it's a typescript? 3. Could you please give an exact code which would illustrate how are you creating new lambda function in CDK project?